# Digester rules xml to populate list of values

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons-digester

I have an SDO-like object that I need to parse with the help of digester rules.
Object can have a list that stores same types as object itself e.g.

```
  class SdoLike{
     private List<SdoLike> listValue;

    public addListValueItem(SdoLike sdoLike){
        this.listValue.add(sdoLike);
       }
    }
```

How to define digester rules for that in xml?

```
<pattern value="ListValue">
            <object-create-rule classname="SdoLike"/>
                    <!--.......... -->
            <set-next-rule methodname="addListValueItem"/>
    </pattern>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. after some time

I placed a rule definition of SdoLike class into a separate file and

```
<pattern value="*/ListValue">
    <object-create-rule classname="tra.ta.ta.SdoLike" />
    <extended-include path="META-INF/digester/SdoLike.xml" />
    <set-next-rule methodname="addListValueItem" />
</pattern>
```

this pattern must not be nested into other patterns.